# How to reduce the img size

Tags: css, html, sections

In my code CSS is no longer working, the CSS which I applied to the sections!

This image doesn't shrink, what am I missing out?

in website: [image]

In HTML Code is:

```
<section  class="sec5 container">
   <div class="blockcontainer">
      <img src="img/campanha.jpg">
   </div>
```

In CSS is:

```
.blockcontainer{
  width: 10%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Comment: (offtopic) You have `.blockcontainer` (without underscore) and `.block_container` (with underscore) That won't work.

Comment: Chrome > Right Click > Inspect Element > Check what CSS rules are being applied or what is overwriting yours

Comment: You aren't defining any dimensions for the image. `.block_container img { width: 100% }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in your CSS,

```
.blockcontainer{
  width: 10%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
.blockcontainer img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

`.block_container` should be changed into `.blockcontainer`

Comment: Try giving dimensions for the image. <img src="img/campanha.jpg" style="width:100%;">

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 .blockcontainer img{
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
     }
```